# Qooxdoo Table with Remote data and pagnation support

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

Anyone have an example code on how to work with qooxdoo ? i am qooxdoo newbie here and i just successfully manage to design my UI in Qooxdoo and i do not grasp coding of table and its Remote data model yet.

Please enlighten me. would be good if theres an example code i can read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qooxdoo has an example showing how to use the remote table model [1]. But this pattern is not designed to support pagination. If you need that, you have to do that yourself somehow with additional controls and setting the data manually.

[1] http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#table~Table_Remote_Model.html

Comment: i had seen that demo but it was quite complex for beginner. Can you give me a code snippet that will make JSON Request to server for specified range, using Qxdoo Remote Table RPC ?

Comment: i am getting use to with table , remote is not tried much , one question , how can i add a footer row (for example , to calculate Total cost at the bottom , which is not part of the model but to show summary data as a static row) , does that can be done?
and is it possible to add buttons at footer of table?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the remote table page you refrenced is too complex for any beginner who going to start with Qooxdoo tables.

This is much better :

http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/0.8/remote_table_model

i am going to test with it. hope that works with 1.5

EDIT:Tested and working fine with 1.5 . I am going to implement a pager using From / To queries.